# ASP.NET MVC - How do Remove log in Cookies from a asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

How to avoid that when logging in, the browser saves this login data and the user can enter even after closing the browser

Thats my login controller

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        var userDTO = new ExpandedUserDTO();

        switch (result)
        {                            
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("RedirectLogin");

            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Falha ao Realizar login, usuário ou senha incorretos.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use [token authentication](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide).

Comment: Look at good explanation [Session vs Token Based Authentication](https://medium.com/@sherryhsu/session-vs-token-based-authentication-11a6c5ac45e4).

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter to `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` determines whether or not the cookie will persist after the browser is closed. If you don't want the cookie to persist, always pass in `false` for this parameter.

See the documentation for this method here - https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2

You could try making the following changes:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, shouldLockout: false);
    var userDTO = new ExpandedUserDTO();

    switch (result)
    {                            
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            return RedirectToAction("RedirectLogin");

        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Falha ao Realizar login, usuário ou senha incorretos.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect *PasswordSignInAsync*-option defines [Session cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Session_cookies) 
 that unfortunately not give 100% guarantee of its destroying. They can be alive after browser crash or power down etc Please take into account the quotation on MDN *"web browsers may use session restoring"*.

Comment: +1 For acknowledging this. The ´IsPersistent´ flag does nothing more than set the cookie lifetime to the maximum configured lifetime rather than ´session´. How the browser handles that lifetime is entirely up to him.